# Where can I safely crash into signs?

Tags: mario-kart-8

When I crash into the start/finish sign on Mario Circuit, it makes the most entertaining noise and doesn't obstruct my movement (and can sometimes even block Red Shells). On which other courses can this happen?

Comment: I can tell you that you cannot on Rumble Volcano, as the sign does not swing there.  But this question may be inappropriate as it encourages a list as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a variety of testing, here are my results:

- The signs on **Mario Circuit**, **Wario Stadium (DS)**, and **Neo Bowser City (3DS) [DLC2]** swing when smacked. Players should veer into them at every opportunity.
- The signs on **Toad's Turnpike (N64)** and **Grumble Volcano (Wii)** can be hit, but won't budge, and you'll just make a fool of yourself.
- Signs on other courses can't be reached, though you still have to be alert when throwing Bananas, or they'll bounce off and hat you.

Comment: "or they'll bounce off and hat you" - wait, hat you? Did you mean hit you? Or can you ricochet bananas such that they land on your head and you get to wear a banana hat?

Comment: Yeah you can indeed bounce bananas off a sign or wall and have them land on your head. It's funny, but it still counts as hitting a banana, so you have to watch it.

Comment: But do you get to wear it as you drive around?

Comment: No unforunately. That would be cool though.